# defaultdict, functions and lambdas

Tags: python, lambda

I've been playing around with default dict and I'm confused

Why does this not work:

**Example 1**

```
def hi(name):
    return "hi " + name

a = defaultdict(hi)
print(a["hello"]("jane"))
```

**Output Example 1**

```
TypeError: hi() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

---

but this does:

**Example 2**

```
def hi(name):
        return "hi " + name

a = {"hello":hi}
print(a["hello"]("jane"))
```

**Output Example 2**

```
hi jane
```

---

also using a lambda would make it work

**Example 3**

```
def hi(name):
    return "hi " + name

a = defaultdict(lambda: hi)
print(a["hello"]("jane"))
```

**Output Example** 3

```
hi jane
```

Why does **Example 1** return an error while **Example 3** doesn't?

What's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a defaultdict doesn't find a key, it calls the function without any parameters. With

```
def hi(name):
    return "hi " + name

a = defaultdict(hi)
a["hello"]
```

, `hi` gets called already, although you wanted it to be called only later. Since `hi` gets called without any parameters by the defaultdict, you're seeing the same error you'd see when manually running `hi()`, i.e. a `TypeError` complaining about the incorrect argument count.

Another way of writing out the lambda (for didactic purposes only) would be

```
def hi(name):
    return "hi " + name

def make_hi():
    return hi

a = defaultdict(make_hi)
print(a["hello"]("jane"))
```

Here, the access to `a["hello"]` calls `make_hi`, which then returns `hi`, which then gets called with the parameters `("jane")`.

Comment: so the moment you assign a value to `a` the `hi` function directly gets called?

Comment: When you write `a["hello"]` on the right side of a `=` or without an `=` at all, that's not an assignment, but simply an access. But yes, upon accessing `a["hello"]` a defaultdict looks whether it finds `"hello"`. If it does not, it calls the `hi` function.

Comment: I get why the lambda works now. your `make_hi` function nailed it.

basically when you say `a["hello"]` the `hi` function automatically gets called but if you use a `lambda`. like **Example 3** when you say a["hello"] the lambda gets called and doing `(jane)` is calling the `hi` function with jane as an argument. am I understanding that right?